# Pchart - Rotate Image

Tags: pchart

Using pchart 2 I am looking for a reliable (hopefully built in) way to move the abscissa "HITS" of a bar chart to the left of the chart rather than the top, and the axis with the name to the bottom of the chart.

Sory, but Im newbie and I cant upload images.

```
                      Hits
                1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
       Pedro    ---------
       Juan     --------------
       Luis     ------
       Miguel   ------------
```

Thats a drawbarchat.